# OKHttp Authenticator not working with Retrofit suspend fun

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, kotlin-coroutines, authenticator

I recently updated Retrofit to `2.7.0` and OKHttp to `3.14.4` to take advantage of suspend fun on Retrofit interfaces.

Besides that, I'm also trying to implement Authenticator for the refresh token logic.

This is the retrofit interface

```
interface OfficeApi {
    @Authenticated
    @POST
    suspend fun getCharacter(): Response<CharacterResponse>
}
```

This is my Authenticator

```
class CharacterAuthenticator : Authenticator {

    override fun authenticate(
        route: Route?,
        response: Response
    ): Request? {
        if (responseCount(response) >= 2) return null

        return response.request()
                        .newBuilder()
                        .removeHeader("Authorization")
                        .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $newToken")
                        .build()

        return null
    }

    private fun responseCount(response: Response?): Int {
        var result = 1
        while (response?.priorResponse() != null) result++
        return result
    }

}
```

This is the retrofit fun call

```
    override suspend fun getCharacter() = safeApiCall(moshiConverter) {
        myApi.getCharacter()
    }
```

This is the `safeApiCall`:

```
suspend fun <T> safeApiCall(
    moshiConverter: MoshiConverter,
    apiCall: suspend () -> Response<T>
): Result<T?, ResultError.NetworkError> {
    return try {
        val response = apiCall()
        if (response.isSuccessful) Result.Success(response.body())
        else {
            val errorBody = response.errorBody()
            val errorBodyResponse = if (errorBody != null) {
                moshiConverter.fromJsonObject(errorBody.string(), ErrorBodyResponse::class.java)
            } else null

            Result.Error(
                ResultError.NetworkError(
                    httpCode = response.code(),
                    httpMessage = response.message(),
                    serverCode = errorBodyResponse?.code,
                    serverMessage = errorBodyResponse?.message
                )
            )
        }
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        Result.Error(ResultError.NetworkError(-1, exception.message))
    }
}
```

The Authenticator is working properly, trying to refresh the token twice and then giving up. The problem is: when it gives up (return null), the execution of retrofit (`safeApiCall` function) does not continue. I don't have any feedback if the call was successful or not.

Is there any problem using Authenticator and Coroutines `suspend fun`?

Comment: Possibly see my answer here, which is a tentative "yes" to your question. I had more success switching away from coroutines to a Call<T> request. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62950438/using-coroutine-runblock-with-the-authenticator-to-handle-401-response-from-retr/63632063#63632063

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't this an infinite loop?

```
while (response?.priorResponse() != null)
```

Shouldn't it be

```
var curResponse: Response? = response
while (curResponse?.priorResponse() != null) {
    result++
    curResponse = curResponse.priorResponse()
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Remove suspend try following code

```
fun getCharacter(): Response<CharacterResponse>
```

Comment: The whole idea is to use the new suspend fun support from Retrofit, so removing is not an alternative.